Reducing an array of objects in JS?
I have fairly symmetrical data I want to reduce:
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    relations: {
      siblings: [
        {
          name: 'Tom',
          age: '20'
          snacks: [
            {
              type: 'yogurt'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Jacob'
          snacks: [
            {
              type: 'cookie',
              amount: '2'
            }
            {
              type: 'brownie',
              amount: '3'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Robert',
    relations: {
      siblings: [
        {
          name: 'Timmy',
          age: '16'
          snacks: [
            {
              type: 'fudge'
            }
            {
              type: 'brownie'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

What I'm trying to produce:
const output = {
  name: ['Bob', 'Robert'],
  relations: {
    siblings: {
      name: ['Tom', 'Jacob', 'Timmy'],
      age: ['20', '16'],
      snacks: {
        type: ['yogurt', 'cookie', 'fudge', 'brownie'],
        amount: ['2', '3']
      }
    }
  }
}

I understand how to do this without recursion, but I wanted a solution that would go deep.
Usually I just use reduce with recursion, but then I realized that I would have to add the value to the current level of the object which I don't know how to do.
const compact = (value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return { [value]: '' }; // turning into an object for the mean time
  }

  if (Array.isArray(object)) { }

  // if object
  return Object.entries(object).reduce((accum, [key, value]) => {
    // Do I have to pass accum[key] into compact here? Is this the correct way to do this?
    accum[key] = compact(value);
   
    return accum;
  }, {});
};


Could you add a [mre]? So some data that actually needs recursion?

This question is similar to: How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

do you have a third level or more? how should look the result?

What's the expected result, if only one element has a property, e.g. age? Do you want to create an array with ony property?

@0stone0 I don't have a minimal reproducible example, the problem point is how would I check the accum without doing accum.relations.siblings = ; Do I have to pass in accum[key] which would retain my object selection position

If you don't have an example requiring recursion, then it's kinda hard for us to just guess how it would look like.

The expected result loses information. How will you know from it who is 16 years old? Is it Jacob? Timmy? And who are the siblings of Bob? Does he have 0, 1, 2 or 3 siblings? This seems a bad structure to work with.

@jabaa The forward complexities are not a problem for me, and I'm pretty much ignoring all that for now. The problem for me is the recursion portion (which I am very bad at).

It seems like the question is unclear. I thought, you are asking for a solution. Is is a fixed recursive structure or do you have to handle the uncle's house and car?

@trincot The point of the output was to see all the possibilities for different keys of an object. The data I'm working with is very symmetrical (I don't have to worry about the nuances many comments are describing). I really just need to compact the objects together and make an array of possibilities for that property.

What do you mean "symmetrical data" data?

@jabaa You mean cases in which there are no duplicates? That would just be a single key with a single value (like age in the example above). I'm not sure what a fixed recursive structure is, but the data depth varies which is why I wanted to use recursion and not static logic statements.

@jabaa Symmetrical as in it follows a pattern both horizontally and vertically with small nuances (unlike asymetrical like age could be a value or an array or an object).

Can you provide a data specification? Is this the complete structure: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxycA5hAPwBcyIArgLYBG0A3ESSHIxLRmCigyHEsigQANnDDAcGGvk5iMwZpOEZa6KNhABtALqiSAXwLmCYAJ4AHFABEZcZAF40mHEY5A

@NinaScholz The levels are variable, which is why I wanted a generic recursive solution.

And this is the complete structure for the result: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4FcA2ZkDeAUMqcnAOYQD8AXMiFgLYBG0A2gLoDcJZIcJhHoYwUUBS68yyKBBxwwwAPYgMdQnxkZgLHBIz102PNLIBfIpaA

@jabaa If 2 in an array share the same key, you can assume the value of that key are of the same type. There is no mixing of data types for a single key, thus it's not that complex of a structure, just variable depth.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. Currently, you're trying to avoid any kind of specification and I can't find a specific question.

@jabaa Looking for js, there are only 3 types in the example I provided - string, array, object. I only have 3 cases in my example code. The problem is the depth and recursion part.

The depth and recursion part is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json WIth only 3 types - string, array, object you don't have a symmetrical structure. Nested data types are a symmetrical structure.

The question was specific... there are only 3 types in the example, and you can assume both horizontal and vertical symmetry of the data... This doesn't seem like a contrived question based on the i/o expectations I provided

IMO it doesn't make sense to treat the keys as abstract elements.  You need to do something different with a relations property compared to a name property.  So I would expect your reduce callback to specifically look for "name" and "relations" rather than trying to handle them all generically via Object.entries.

@jabaa The answer doesn't come close to what I'm asking. I also feel like you're getting caught up in word semantics. Looking at the example above, I think you should know what I mean by symmetrical. The objects in the array share the same keys and the values are of the same data structure type.

@James Basically I have 5 huge data files. I want to get schematics (possibilities) of each properties (however these properties are variable based on the files). The data is very symmetrical in terms of the arrays contain "relations.siblings" with an object with "name" = a string

Here is what I would propose: divide functionality into two different functions; one for summarizing a given object, and another for merging two objects that are already summarized.
Then it could be like this:


function merge(a, b) {
    const keys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])];
    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key,
              !Object.hasOwn(a, key) ? b[key]
            : !Object.hasOwn(b, key) ? a[key]
            : Array.isArray(a[key])  ? [...new Set([...a[key], ...b[key]])]
            : merge(a[key], b[key])
    ]));
}

function summarize(obj) {
    return  Object(obj) !== obj ? [obj] // Primitive is wrapped in array
          : Array.isArray(obj)  ? obj.reduce((acc, item) => merge(acc, summarize(item)), {})
          : Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, summarize(value)]))
}

// Demo on the input in the question:
const data = [{name: 'Bob',relations: {siblings: [{name: 'Tom',age: '20'},{name: 'Jacob'}]}},{name: 'Robert',relations: {siblings: [{name: 'Timmy',age: '16'}]}}];
const result = summarize(data);
console.log(result);




Thanks Trincot, I'm just reading over the code in my editor trying to figure out what was the concept I was missing. I think your code is basically aggregating everything on a loop into an object then merging it with the current iteration, but I have to read it again.


Usually I just use reduce with recursion, but then I realized that I would have to add the value to the current level of the object

Pass that current-level object as a second parameter to your recursive function:
function compactInto(value, target, path) { // path only for debugging
  if (typeof value != 'object' || value == null) {
    if (!target) target = [];
    else if (!Array.isArray(target)) throw new Error(`${path.join(',')} is sometimes a ${value && typeof value} and sometimes an object`);
    target.push(value);
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    for (const element of value) {
      target = compactInto(element, target, path);
    }
  } else {
    if (!target) target = {};
    else if (Array.isArray(target)) throw new Error(`${path.join(',')} is sometimes a ${target[0] && typeof targeŧ[0]} and sometimes an object`);
    for (const key of value) {
      path.push(key);
      target[key] = compactInto(value[key], target[key], path);
      path.pop();
    }
  }
  return target;
}
function compact(value) {
  return compactInto(value, null, []);
}


Thank you Bergi! Both answers provided were in my head before I asked, but this method was the one I was looking for originally. Thank you a ton for adding this method.

Just another code.


const
    data = [{ name: 'Bob', relations: { siblings: [{ name: 'Tom', age: '20',  snacks: [{ type: 'yogurt' }] }, { name: 'Jacob', snacks: [{ type: 'cookie', amount: '2' }, { type: 'brownie', amount: '3' }] }] } }, { name: 'Robert', relations: { siblings: [{ name: 'Timmy', age: '16', snacks: [{ type: 'fudge' }, { type: 'brownie' }] }] } }],
    getData = (array, target = {}) => array.reduce((t, o) => {
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => {
                if (v && typeof v === 'object') getData([].concat(v), target[k] ??= {});
                else {
                    target[k] ??= [];
                    if (!target[k].includes(v)) target[k].push(v);
                }
            });
        return t;
    }, target),
    result = getData(data);
    
console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




Hi Nina, I think I understand your idea is to statically target each instance. However, I have many data structures variable depth, albeit the data is very symmetrical. I'll keep working at it, hopefully I can figure it out.

what is "symmetrical"? i know only data with same structure for every level. what do you have?

By symmetrical I mean compactable, as in you could compact arrays of objects with arrays of objects with each level of objects having the same keys. Basically my example above but with more depth of the same type (e.g. if you copy the example and repeated it within each of the arrays again)

please add an example with at least three levels (to the question). and the wanted result.

Basically, I want to get schematics of data files. Since all the objects follow a pattern as show in the example above, I want to get the possibilities of each object property 6 levels deep.

I updated the question with another level
